# WPF: Making Properties of embedded control from template in custom control available

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a Custom Control `IconMD` with the Properties `IconName`,`OverlayName` and `OverlayPosition`

I have embedded this Control in another Custom Control `IconButton` like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
    <Border 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Grid>
            <local:IconMD
                x:Name="_ButtonIcon"
                OverlayPosition="{TemplateBinding OverlayPosition}"
                IconName="{TemplateBinding IconName}"
                OverlayName="{TemplateBinding OverlayIconName}"
            />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The only purpose of the Dependency Properties `OverlayPosition`, `IconName` and `OverlayIconName` of this `IconButton` Control are simply to be passed through to the embedded Icon - the same idea as `BorderBrush` etc.

Now, as I also have `IconToggleButton` and `IconRepeatButton` (which inherit from the respective Base Classes and cannot inherit from `IconButton`!?), i must repeat this pattern for each of them. Should the capabilities of my `IconMD` Class grow, i would have to expand this pattern in every Custom Control that uses it.

How can I simply make the (properties of the) named `IconMD` Control "_ButtonIcon" available outside of my `IconButton`?

I would imagine instead of this

```
<imCC:IconButton
    IconName="mdi-account-card-details"
    OverlayIconName="mdi-multiplication-box"/>
```

writing something like this

```
<imCC:IconButton
    _ButtonIcon.IconName="mdi-account-card-details"
    _ButtonIcon.OverlayName="mdi-multiplication-box"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attached properties instead of normal dependency properties (create in visual studio with snipped `propa`).

If you create `IconName` as attached property in class `IconButton`, you set it as follows:

```
<imCC:IconButton
    imCC:IconButton.IconName="mdi-account-card-details"
    ...
```

And use in the `ControlTemplate` like this:

```
<local:IconMD
    x:Name="_ButtonIcon"
    IconName="{Binding Path=(local:IconButton.IconName),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I was looking for, but It has to be the other way around, the properties have to be defined - only once - in the IconMD Class - IconMD has the IconName as Attached property, then I set it like 
<imCC:IconButton
    imCC:IconMD.IconName="mdi-account-card-details"
    ...

and use it in controltemplate like 

<local:IconMD
    x:Name="_ButtonIcon"
    IconName="{Binding Path=(local:IconMD.IconName),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    ...

Comment: Yea, it doesn't really matter where you decide to implement the attached properties... placing them in `IconButton` is just an example and can be replaced by `IconMD` or some `ButtonIcon` class or whatever.

Comment: Yes. Within my logic "IconButton, IconRepeatButton, IconToggleButton" all have "Icon(MD)s" that need to be set. Imo that logic should be reflected in your answer  - but i might be wrong :). Anyway, accepted as it was easier to understand than the other answer that actually proposes the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the properties as attached properties that you can set on any `UIElement` or `Button` element.

**Attached Properties Overview:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBubbleSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IconName", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperties));

        public static void SetIconName(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty, value);
        }
        public static string GetIconName(UIElement element)
        {
            return (string)element.GetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<imCC:IconButton xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    local:AttachedProperties.IconName="mdi-account-card-details" />
```

Comment: Even though this was a bit harder to understand, it's what I wanted, but I'm defining the Attached Properties in the IconMD class.

Comment: You could do this if you want to. But you will still be able to set them on any UIElement. It doesn't really matter in which class they are defined.